# Replace last occurrence of substring

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Given this string:

> .ABC,.123,.FGH,.QDG

How can I most-efficiently use PL/SQL to output (note the ", and"):

> abc, 123, fgh, and qdg

So far I've got `LOWER(REPLACE('.ABC,.123,.FGH,.QDG', '.', ' '))`, which yields

> abc, 123, fgh, qdg

How do I get that "and" after "fgh,", but before "qdg" ("fgh, and qdg")? Must I use `INSTR()` and `SUBSTR()`, or is there a function that can just replace the last space with " and "?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on what you used already...  use `regexp_replace` with `instr`

```
with cte as(
select LOWER(REPLACE('.ABC,.123,.FGH,.QDG', '.', ' ')) as val from dual)
select regexp_replace(val,' ',' and ',instr(val ,' ',-1))
from cte;
```

or `regexp_replace(val,', ',' and ',instr(val ,', ',-1))` if you want to get rid of the last comma too.

[image]

Comment: This gets the head-nod because it is easier to implement in a PL/SQL execution block.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
select substr(text, 1, last_space_pos) || 'and' || substr(text, last_space_pos) new_text
from
(select text, instr(text, ' ', -1) last_space_pos
 from
 (select LOWER(REPLACE('.ABC,.123,.FGH,.QDG', '.', ' ')) text from dual)
);
```

The function call `instr(text, ' ', -1)` finds the position of the last space, and the `substr` calls break the string at that point so that we can insert 'and'.  The use of nested `select` statements avoids having to repeat any complex expressions.